# Exercise 3C.4 of Isaac's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

Let $M$ be minimal normal in finite solvable group $G$, and assume that $M=C_G(M)$. Show that $G$ splits over $M$ and that all complements for $M$ in $G$ are conjugate.

Hint. Let $L/M$ be minimal normal in $G/M$, and note that $L/M$ is a $q$-group for some prime $q$. Show that $q$ does not divide $|M|$, and consider a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $L$.

Comment: what have you done?

Answer (score 3):

In brief: if $q$ divides $|M|$, then $L$ is a $q$-group, so $M \cap Z(L) \ne 1$, hence by minimality of $M$ $M \le Z(L)$ contradicting $M=C_G(M)$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $L$, $N = N_G(P)$. Show $N \cap M = 1$ (otherwise we get $M \cap Z(L) \ne 1$ again), hence $N$ is the required complement, and all complements are normalizers of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $L$, so they are all conjugate in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

### Filling the blanks in [Derek's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617987/269050)

**A reason why $N\cap M=1$**

Put $|L/M|=q^d$. Then
$$
    |L| = |M||L:M| = |M|q^d.
$$
It follows that $|Q|=q^d$ and so $L=MQ$. The Frattini Argument gives us
$$
    G=NL=NMQ= NQM= NM.
$$
Since $M$ is normal and abelian, both $N$ and $M$ normalize $N\cap M$. Then $N\cap M\triangleleft NM=G$. In consequence, we must have $N\cap M=1$ or $M$. But the latter case is impossible:
\begin{align*}
    M \subseteq N &\iff N=NM=G\\
        &\iff Q\triangleleft G\\
        &\implies Q\leftrightarrow M  &&\text{; commutes with}\\
        &\implies Q\subseteq C_G(M)=M\\
        &\to\leftarrow
\end{align*}

---

**Conjuagted complements**

Let $N_1$ be another complement of $M$. We have to show that $N_1$ is a conjugate of $N$. Consider the diagram

[image]

where $\theta$ and $\theta_1$ are the isomorphisms given by both splits of $G$ on $M$, i.e., $\phi(zy)=y$ and $\phi_1(zy_1)=y_1$ for $z\in M$, $y\in N$ and $y_1\in N_1$. In particular, the inclusions $\iota\colon N\to G$ and $\iota_1\colon N_1\to G$ are, respectively, sections of $\phi$ and $\phi_1$.

**Step 1:** $Q_1\triangleleft M$ *because $\theta_1\circ\theta^{-1}$ is an isomorphism*

**Step 2:** $N_G(Q_1)\triangleleft N_G(Q_1)M=G$ *because $M$ is abelian and normal*

**Step 3:** $N_G(Q_1)\cap M=1$. *You will use that $C_G(M)=M$*

**Step 4:** $Q_1\subseteq L$. *Take $w_1\in Q_1$, $w_1=\theta_1\circ\theta^{-1}(w)$ with $w\in Q$. Then*

[image]

**Step 5:** $Q_1\in\text{Syl}_q(L)$

**Step 6:** Write $Q_1=Q^x$. Then $N_1 = N_G(Q_1) = N_G(Q^x) = N_G(Q)^x = N^x$